# I would dynamically add the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes to each anchor in my html page but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I would dynamically add the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes to each anchor in my html page when the page loads.

I tried in all the ways I know but I can not get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="init()">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function init(){
   startTimers();
   initLinksProperties();
}

function initLinksProperties(){
   var onMouseOverColor = 'red';
   var onMouseOutColor = '#00BFFF';

   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
      links[i].onmouseover = function(){ cambiaColore(i, onMouseOverColor); };
      links[i].onmouseout = function(){ cambiaColore(i, onMouseOutColor); }; 
   }
}

function cambiaColore(index, color){
   var element = document.links[index];
   element.style.color = color;
}
```

I also tried with:

```
links[i].onmouseover = cambiaColore(i, onMouseOverColor);
links[i].onmouseout = cambiaColore(i, onMouseOutColor);

links[i].addEventListener('onmouseover', cambiaColore(i, onMouseOverColor));
links[i].addEventListener('onmouseout', cambiaColore(i, onMouseOutColor));

links[i].setAttribute('onmouseover', cambiaColore(i, onMouseOverColor));
links[i].setAttribute('onmouseout', cambiaColore(i, onMouseOutColor));
```

cambiaColore is a function that changes the color of the link.

I have no syntax errors but nothing happens.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When trying your code I had "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" error in this function :

```
function cambiaColore(index, color){
   var element = document.links[index];
   element.style.color = color;
}
```

seems like "document.links[index]" doesn't return your element.

So I change your function a bit, instead of having index as first argument you have the element itself.

```
function cambiaColore(element, color){
   element.style.color = color;
}
```

And in mouseover and mouseout functions I pass the element as first argument :

```
function initLinksProperties(){
   var onMouseOverColor = 'red';
   var onMouseOutColor = '#00BFFF';

   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
       links[i].onmouseover = function(e){ cambiaColore(e.target, onMouseOverColor); };
       links[i].onmouseout = function(e){ cambiaColore(e.target, onMouseOutColor); }; 
    }
}
```

entire code :

```
function init() {
   startTimers();
   initLinksProperties();
}

function initLinksProperties(){
   var onMouseOverColor = 'red';
   var onMouseOutColor = '#00BFFF';

   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   console.log(links);
   for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
      links[i].onmouseover = function(e){ cambiaColore(e.target, onMouseOverColor); };
      links[i].onmouseout = function(e){ cambiaColore(e.target, onMouseOutColor); }; 
   }
}

function cambiaColore(element, color){
   element.style.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

document.links is not accessible in cambiaColore.  Pass the element or the event so you can retrieve the target you want to change.  Right now you're trying to change undefined.

```js
(function(window, document, undefined)
{
  initLinksProperties();
})(window, window.document);

function initLinksProperties(){
   var onMouseOverColor = 'red';
   var onMouseOutColor = '#00BFFF';

   var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
      links[i].addEventListener('mouseover', 
        function(event)
        {
          var element = event.target;
          cambiaColore(element, onMouseOverColor);
        }, false);
      links[i].addEventListener('mouseout', 
        function(event)
        {
          var element = event.target;
          cambiaColore(element, onMouseOutColor);
        }, false); 
   }
}

function cambiaColore(element, color){
   element.style.color = color;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Link 1</a>
<a href="">Link 2</a>
<a href="">Link 3</a>
<a href="">Link 4</a>
<a href="">Link 5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the function `cambiaColore()` is called, the value of the `i` variable has changed because the loop already finished. You don't need to pass `index` or `element` as others have suggested. You just need to use `event.target`:

```
function cambiaColore(index, color) {
    // no need to use index or element. You can remove it.
    event.target.style.color = color;
}
```

Link for the complete solution: https://jsfiddle.net/h6xhajtd/

If you want to know more about `event.target`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/target